# Scroll при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Если человек перезагружает страницу, когда он прокрутил например до середины, то класс не добавляется, хотя он уже выше 1px от верха страницы, как сюда добавить проверку, что если страницы прокручена дальше 1px, даже при перезагрузке добавлялся класс.

```
if(window.innerWidth < 768){
    var h_hght = 1;
} else {
    var h_hght = 45;
}
var h_mrg = 0;
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var top = $(this).scrollTop();
       var elem = $('#head-scroll');
       if (top+h_mrg < h_hght) {
        elem.css('top', (h_hght-top));
        elem.removeClass('fixed');
       } else {
        elem.css('top', h_mrg);
        elem.addClass('fixed');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите Ваш scroll-обработчик в функцию и поставьте функцию как обработчик события load и scroll. Например так:

```
function scroll () {
   var top = $(this).scrollTop();
   var elem = $('#head-scroll');
   if (top+h_mrg < h_hght) {
    elem.css('top', (h_hght-top));
    elem.removeClass('fixed');
   } else {
    elem.css('top', h_mrg);
    elem.addClass('fixed');
   }
}

window.addEventListener("load", scroll);
window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает как надо!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    // После готовности страницы
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 1)  // Проверка состояния прокрутки
    {
     // ваши действия
    }
});
```

***Надеюсь помог!***